# Linq to entities insert EF 1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a 2 Entity : Person (Id, CategoryId) and Category(Id).

Now when I try to insert a new Person with only the Id and CategoryId it throws an exception about the Person having a relationship with Category.

The following code doesn't work:

```
Person newPerson = new Person();
newPerson.Id = 1;
newPerson.CategoryId = 1;
context.AddToPersonSet(newPerson);
context.SaveChanges
```

This code works

```
Person newPerson = new Person();
newPerson.Id = 1;
newPerson.Category = context.CategorySet.Where(cat=> cat.Id == 1).First(); 
newPerson.CategoryId = 1;
context.AddToPersonSet(newPerson);
context.SaveChanges
```

Is there another way to insert without having to fetch the Category entity ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Exactly what doesn't work in the first example?

Comment: Does a row exist in the Category table with an Id value of 1?

Comment: Yes it does exist in the Database. It throws an updateexception in the first example : Entities in 'Myentity.PersonSet' participate in the 'FK_Persons_Category' relationship. 0 related 'Category' were found. 1 'Category' is expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF 4 with FK associations your first code would "just work", so I'll assume you're using EF 1, although you don't say.

Workaround for EF 1 is:

```
Person newPerson = new Person();
newPerson.Id = 1;
// substitute the correct strings for your mapping.
newPerson.CategoryReference.EntityKey = 
    new EntityKey("MyEntities.Categories", "CategoryId", 1);
context.AddToPersonSet(newPerson);
context.SaveChanges();
```

You should not have `Person.CategoryId` mapped *at all* in EF 1. It shouldn't even be a part of the `Person` type.

Obviously, the best solution is to use EF 4. But if that's not an option, the above works fine.

Answer (score 1):

similar: [best practise/way for master detail / multi table Insert in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158795/best-practise-way-for-master-detail-multi-table-insert-in-entity-framework)